# "( was unexpected at this time" with if statement

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, command-prompt

I am new to batch and making my first batch project with custom commands using doskey, mainly for myself. I have been successful with all of my scripts in my project up until this point. I have a command that tells the user all the commands (5 so far), much like the help command, except for some reason I am getting errors (described in the title). I might have an idea where the error is coming from, but I have no idea how to fix it. I have checked multiple sources but none of them are even close to what I need to fix, so here is my code:

```
@echo off
IF "%~1" == "" (
    echo For more information on a specific command, type CMDS command-name
    echo ADD            Adds specified NUM amount to variable
    echo NUM            Sets the NUM amount to a specified value
    echo RESET          Sets variable to 0
    echo SETNUM         Sets variable to a specified value
    echo SUB            Subtracts specified NUM amount from variable
)
IF /I %1 == ADD (
    echo The ADD command will add the amount specified from the NUM command to a variable specified as num
)
IF /I %1 == NUM (
    echo The NUM command will set the variable specified as num to a specific value
)
IF /I %1 == RESET (
    echo The RESET command will reset the variable specified as num to 0
)
IF /I %1 == SETNUM (
    echo The SETNUM command will set the amount that gets added to/subtracted from the variable specified as num to a specific value
)
IF /I %1 == SUB (
    echo The SUB command will subtract the amount specified from the NUM command from a variable specified as num
)
IF not /I %1 == ADD (
    IF not /I %1 == NUM (
        IF not /I %1 == RESET (
            IF not /I %1 == SETNUM (
                IF not /I %1 == SUB (
                    echo %1 is not a command! //I think the error is coming from one of the if statements in these nested ifs, because this is the only thing that doesn't work
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
@echo on
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To start with, improve your syntax, to make it more robust: ```IF /I "%~1" == "ADD"```, ```IF /I "%~1" == "NUM"```, ```IF /I "%~1" == "RESET"```, ```IF /I "%~1" == "SETNUM"```,  ```IF /I "%~1" == "SUB"```. Then more importantly , as well as using the doublequotes, please notice that it is ```IF /I NOT``` not ```IF NOT /I```. i.e.  ```IF /I NOT "%~1" == "ADD"```, ```IF /I NOT "%~1" == "NUM"```, ```IF /I NOT "%~1" == "RESET"```, ```IF /I NOT "%~1" == "SETNUM"```, ```IF /I NOT "%~1" == "SUB"```.

Comment: The issue is that the syntax of the `if` statement *requires* the `/i` to appear before the `not`. applying the quotations method of the first `if` statement to every `if` statement will make the code better.  Note that the string on *both* sides needs to be quoted. BTW - if you fail to supply a parameter as `%` to this program, it will generate the same error message as you report, because the value of `%1` will be *nothing*

Comment: since you're new just learn powershell and steer clear from the nasty legacy cmd. Everything is easier in powershell including customizations, psreadline is far more extensible than doskey

Comment: @phuclv I don't know anything about PowerShell, is it compatible with cmd prompt and .bat files?

Comment: @ArcadeSmasher no, if it's compatible with cmd then it won't be great and powerful at all. Cmd is terrible because it must maintain DOS compatibility so lots of things are impossible to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch is a really, *really* broken "programming language".

If you do not provide an argument, consider what happens here:

```
IF /I %1 == ADD (
    echo The ADD command will add the amount specified from the NUM command to a variable specified as num
)
```

The `%1` is replaced with nothing. Which results in:

```
IF /I  == ADD (
    echo The ADD command will add the amount specified from the NUM command to a variable specified as num
)
```

The solution is to always use `"%~1" == "something"`.

And as Compo pointed out, it's `IF /I NOT`.

Maybe don't compulsively put `@echo off` in your file if you're trying to debug it... It would have shown what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but should I put the quotation marks on the if not statements, like this: `IF /I not "%1" == "SUB" (echo %1 is not a command!)`? because if I do, it just gives me a new error: ` is not a command!`

Comment: Yes. That's not an error, that's your faulty program logic. If no argument is provided, it still goes all the way inside those nested if statements.

Comment: So is there a way to not get that error, or is it just not possible? Maybe I could also check if there is no arguments?

Comment: Again, it is not an error. It's your program's last echo statement.

Comment: So I nested another if statement and it works fine now. This is it: `IF /I not "%~1" == "" (echo %1 is not a command!)`. I'm going to accept your answer.

Comment: To prevent the code flow from "running through", just add `goto :eof` as a last line (but before the closing `)`) to the "help" section to end the script.